# how do I check linear independence of m vectors, given the m-1 first vectors are independence?

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms

I have a set of m-1 vectors of size n, they are independence. I want to add another vector and to check if the m vectors are still independence. It is known m < n. I am looking for a good algorithm & running time.
Thanks

Comment: I guess you want to use the linear independence of the $\ m-1\ $ vectors for a shortcut. Is that right ?

Comment: nope, just it is greater the the number of vectors you have, so you cannot negate it directly.. and yes this is what I am looking for

Comment: Then, determining the rank (as mentioned in my answer) should be a suitable approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following criterion :

If you have $\ m-1\ $ linear independent vectors, then adding the $\ m\ $- th vector gives again a linear independent set if and only if the $\ m\ $ - th vector is not a linear-combination of the original $\ m-1\ $ vectors, in other words there are no real numbers $\ a_1,\cdots, a_{m-1}\ $ with $$\sum_{j=1}^{m-1} a_jv_j=v_m$$

For the check I suggest to collect the vectors in a matrix and determine the rank.

Comment: How does this help for checking?

Comment: @mathreadler It hints at setting up a matrix equation which can be used as a check, at least that's what I gathered.

Comment: Sure it may hint but then maybe it can be good to at least write hint.

Comment: Thanks, I got the theory. I am asking how to do it, I mean how do you check it? What kind of algorithm and hat would be the run time complexity?

Comment: @ShaharMazia I did a bit of searching online, from what I can see it looks like setting up a matrix equation and solving it using the Gaussian elimination algorithm is your best bet, other than randomised algorithms. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6194/how-to-compute-the-rank-of-a-matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Project the new vector on the others and remove.

If anything remains afterwards then they are linearly independent.